# Reducing nesting

Tags: java, android

Imaging in some code you have a lot of checks to do and they must be done in a specific order. For example:

pseudo code:

```
int a, b, c, ...... y, z
a = Random(0,10);
if (a > 5)
    b = Random(a,100);
    if (b > 50)
        c = Random(b,200);
        if (c > 100)
            ......
            ...... if (y > 10000)
                       z = Random(y, 11000);
int d = a + b + c + ...... + y + z;
```

The above calculation must be done in an order and generates a lot of nesting which makes the code difficult to read in the end. I know the above algorithm can be dealt with by using an int array and a for loop but what if the calculation is something much more complicated and is different after each check? What would be the best way to solve this?

This is what I have come up with:

```
while (true)
{
    if (a < 6)
        break;

    b = Random(a,100);
    if (b < 51)
        break;

    c = Random(b,200);
    if (c < 101)
        break;

    ......

    if (y < 10001)
        break;

    z = Random(y, 11000);
}   
int d = a + b + c + ...... + y + z;
```

But, the Android Studio is complaining the `while` statement does not loop...

---

OK, let's look at a different example:

```
int a, b, c, ...... y, z
    a = Random(0,10);
    if (a > 5)
        b = Random(a,100) + 1 * 5; // some complicated operation
        if (b > 50)
            c = Random(b,200) + 4 - log10(,10); // some more complicated operation
            if (c > 100)
                ......
                ...... if (y > 10000)
                           z = Random(y, 11000) * 999^a - b + log2(log10(d)); // well you get the idea

    int d = a * b + c - ...... / y ^ z;
```

---

***Compilable example:***

activity_main.xml: just add a `TextView` widget with an ID `resultTextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import static java.lang.Math.log10;
import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        doSomeCal();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView)).setText(String.valueOf(doSomeCal()));
    }

private int doSomeCal() {
    int a, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
    int val = 0;
    Random r = new Random();

    a = r.nextInt(10);
    if (a > 5) {
        b = takeRandom(r, a, 100) + 5;
        if (b > 50) {
            c = takeRandom(r, b, 200) + 4 - (int) log10(111);
            if (c > 100) {
                d = takeRandom(r, c, 500) * 6 + (int) log10(c);
                if (d > 230) {
                    e = takeRandom(r, d, 11000) * 999 ^ a - b + (int) log10(log10(d));
                    val = a * b + c * e - d;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        val = -999;
    }

    if (val > 516) {
        if (d > 200)
            return e > 1000 ? val + d + e : val + d;
        else
            return e > 1000 ? val + 20 + e : val;
    }
    if (val > 432) {
        if (b > 30) {
            return c > 60 ? val + b : val + c;
        } else {
            return val + c;
        }
    }
    if (val > 20) {
        if (b > 30) {
            return a > 3 ? val + a : val + b;
        } else {
            return a < 6 ? val - a : val - b;
        }
        if (val < 0) {
            if (a > 3 && b > 30)
                return c < 80 ? val - a * b + c : val + a + b;
        }
    }
    return val + 999;
}
```

Comment: Note how each level of nesting is similar and write a method that performs that exact task. You will need several parameters for the different values.

Comment: You should also learn about arrays and `List`. These are almost always better tools than using 26 different variables (or more).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm assuming that that was just a product of oversimplification but looking at the while loop, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I stated in the op that the operation after each if statement could be different...I'm fully aware that the exact code in the example could be replaced with a for loop

Comment: I will help significantly if you can provide a **complete** example. By this I mean something that can actually be compiled and run. You don't have to illustrate 100 nor even twenty levels. 4 or 5 is sufficient because this is already too deep.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks but I don't have a complete example. This is just a question comes from a wild thinking. I think Sam has answered my question: when nesting is necessary, I will have to use nesting and any other means such as inverse logic may only complicate it performance wise..

Comment: If this is important enough to you, take some time to create a complete example. This will help you clarify your thinking. You might even discover a good solution. If you don't, you will be able to explain the problem much better to other people in order to get suggestions.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the problem is every real/complete example I can think of at the moment can be optimised (such as combine checks or loops) to avoid multiple nestings. If anything comes up in the future, I will update this question and mention you if you are interested.

Comment: The code you have here is far from complete. `......` is not valid Java syntax. Yes, I understand that this means you elided some code and I can understand the pattern. However, it is difficult to provide a working alternative because of the vagueness that a compiler cannot understand.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No.. the examples above are just to illustrate the ideas and I did not mean they are complete. Whatever I can think of now, i.e. a complete example, does not reach a level of complication that I cannot simplify the algorithm by myself. In other words, I'm unable to provide a real problem with a complete example to demonstrate my question.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot illustrate the complexities with a nesting level of 5 instead of 26?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164104/discussion-between-anthony-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: I do not think chat will be productive here. If you need further help, you must create an example which illustrates exactly what you are asking about. The example must compile without error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yea, I wanted to say something but then I thought, OK, let me just add an example... it did take a few minutes though.

Comment: Well the added example can also be optimised quite easily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you need to perform nested checks then you need to perform nested checks.  You can inverse your logic to bail if a check fails, but this will only save indentation and lengthen your code with many calls to `break;` or `return;`.

---

Your loop doesn't save any code, in fact it introduces more and as far as I see does nothing... maybe you'll like the aesthetics of this:

```
int[] minimums = new int[] {5, 50, ...};
int[] upperRanges = new int[] {100, 200, ...};
int[] values = new int[minimums.length];
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < minimums.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Random(0, upperRanges[i]); // still pseudo code
    result += values[i];
    if (values[i] <= minimums[i])
        break;
}
// result is the cumulative sum
// If you don't reference values later, then you can replace it with a regular int to be used again and again.
```

FYI, `values` [initialized to all zeros.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Comment: Well, thanks but as I stated in the op that the operation after each if statement could be different...I'm fully aware that the exact code in the example could be replaced with a for loop

Comment: Ha, seems I forgot the answer to your overall question... Sorry. I updated this with the answer you probably already know.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap your data in an object (array is ok) I would use [chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) (or at least something close to that) and let objects manage what's needed. This will yield more verbose declaration, but checking itself will be much cleaner.

I'm using anonymous classes, but you can break it up into normal classes to make code more readable.

```
public static void validate(){
    int[] sampleDataSet = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    //generate validators
    Validator[] validators = {
            new Validator() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid(int[] data, int jobId) {
                    //do any check needed, modify data set as well
                    data[jobId] = 1;
                    return true;
                }
            },
            new Validator() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid(int[] data, int jobId) {
                    //do any check needed, modify data set as well
                    data[jobId] = 3;
                    return false;
                }
            }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
        if(!validators[i].isValid(sampleDataSet, i))
            break;
    }

}

interface Validator{
    boolean isValid(int data[], int jobId);
}
```